# How can i replace true and false with 1 and 0 exporting to txt

Tags: ruby

im new to rails and it seems like a really easy problem, but i dont get it. 
So i want to extrakt a .txt file out of my database. I want to export the boolean data with "true" and "false" as "0" and "1". Here is my code:

```
if File.exist?("nanny_Input.inc")
  File.delete("nanny_Input.inc")
end
f=File.new("nanny_Input.inc", "w")


printf(f, "parameter FV(i) / \n")
@nannies = Nanny.all
@nannies.each { |nann|
  printf(f, nann.name + "\s" + nann.fuehrerschein.to_s + "\n") }
printf(f, "/;\n\n")
```

And nann.fuehrerschein ist boolean so i just want the output "0" and "1". Sorry for such an easy question but it would be nice if someone of you help me :) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check if the `boolean` value is `true` or `false`. You can make use of ternary operator in this case

```
printf(f, "#{nann.name} #{nann.fuehrerschein ? 1 : 0}\n") }
```

Here is how this will work -

- For each record it will check if `nann.fuehrerschein == true`
- If the condition is true it will return `1`
- Else it will return `0`

Also, you can change your code a bit

```
File.open('nanny_Input.inc', 'w') do |file|
  file.puts"parameter FV(i) /"

  @nannies = Nanny.all
  @nannies.each do |nanny|
    file.puts "#{nanny.name} #{nanny.fuehrerschein ? 1 : 0}"
  end
end
```